# Need help to use an image from an array combined with a number

Tags: arrays, swift, uicollectionview

I want to use the image from the placeStarsIcon array using the placeStarsCount. So instead of showing the number 5 from placeStarsCount I want to display "5stars.png" in the `cell.placeStarsIcon.image`

This is how i try but i get an error:`Cannot subscript a value of type '[UIImage]' with an argument of type '[Int]'`:

`cell.placeStarsIcon.image = placeStarsIcon[plaaceStarsCount]`

Here is the code:

```swift
class FindLocalViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

       let placeName = ["Place Name 0", "Place Name 1", "Place Name 2"]
       let placeDescription = ["Place Description 0. Text to see if can go to more than 2 lines because we need.", "Place Description 1. Text to see if can go to more than 2 lines because we need.", "Place Description 2. Text to see if can go to more than 2 lines because we need."]

        //Thats the number of stars for each placeName. 5 stars, 2 stars, 0 stars.
        let placeStarsCount = [5, 2, 0]

        let placeStarsIcon = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "0stars.png") , #imageLiteral(resourceName: "1stars.png") , #imageLiteral(resourceName: "2stars.png"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "3stars.png"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "4stars.png"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "5stars.png")]


       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
       }

       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return placeName.count
       }


       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

           let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as!
           FindLocalCollectionViewCell

           cell.placeName.text = placeName[indexPath.row]
           cell.placeDescription.text = placeDescription[indexPath.row]

            /*
            Here i want to use the image from the placeStarsIcon array using the placeStarsCount
            So instead of showing the number 5 from placeStarsCount i want to display "5stars.png" in the cell.placeStarsIcon.image

            This is how i try but i get an error:
            Cannot subscript a value of type '[UIImage]' with an argument of type '[Int]'


            */

           cell.placeStarsIcon.image = placeStarsIcon[placeStarsCount]



           return cell


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
cell.placeStarsIcon.image = placeStarsIcon[placeStarsCount]
```

with

```
cell.placeStarsIcon.image = UIImage(named:"\(placeStarsCount[indexPath.row])stars.png")
```

and get rid of `placeStarsIcon`  array , btw you can have a struct instead of separate arrays like

```
struct Place {
   let name,desc:String
   let imgNumber:Int
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This workedI  Much apreciated.
I guess i need to learn about struct.
Coming soon in next lessons.
I still have a lot to learn ;)
Thanks again

Comment: @furiousteam don't forget to accept the answer if helped